# Custom open cart module install - Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am trying to write a custom module that will hook into `post.order.history.add` event and do a custom action. This is my module structure & code so far:

**admin\controller\module\mysite.php**

```
<?php

class ControllerModuleMysite extends Controller
{
    private $error;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->error  = array();
        $this->logger = new Log('MySite.log');
    }

    /* Event Hooks */

    public function install()
    {
        $this->load->model('extension/event');

        $this->model_extension_event->addEvent('mysite_NewOrder', 'post.order.history.add', 'module/mysite/on_order_history_add');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        $this->load->model('extension/event');

        $this->model_extension_event->deleteEvent('mysite_NewOrder');
    }

    /* Admin Config Handler */

    public function index()
    {
        // Loading the language file of mysite
        $this->load->language('module/mysite');

        // Set the title of the page to the heading title in the Language file
        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        // Load the Setting Model  (All of the OpenCart Module & General Settings are saved using this Model )
        $this->load->model('setting/setting');

        // Start If: Validates and check if data is coming by save (POST) method
        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate())
        {
            // Parse all the coming data to Setting Model to save it in database.
            $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('mysite', $this->request->post);

            // To display the success text on data save
            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            // Redirect to the Module Listing
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
        }

        // Assign the language data for parsing it to view
        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $data['text_edit']           = $this->language->get('text_edit');
        $data['text_enabled']        = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
        $data['text_disabled']       = $this->language->get('text_disabled');
        $data['text_content_top']    = $this->language->get('text_content_top');
        $data['text_content_bottom'] = $this->language->get('text_content_bottom');
        $data['text_column_left']    = $this->language->get('text_column_left');
        $data['text_column_right']   = $this->language->get('text_column_right');

        $data['entry_code']       = $this->language->get('entry_code');
        $data['entry_layout']     = $this->language->get('entry_layout');
        $data['entry_position']   = $this->language->get('entry_position');
        $data['entry_status']     = $this->language->get('entry_status');
        $data['entry_sort_order'] = $this->language->get('entry_sort_order');

        $data['button_save']       = $this->language->get('button_save');
        $data['button_cancel']     = $this->language->get('button_cancel');
        $data['button_add_module'] = $this->language->get('button_add_module');
        $data['button_remove']     = $this->language->get('button_remove');

        // This Block returns the warning if any
        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        // This Block returns the error code if any
        if (isset($this->error['code'])) {
            $data['error_code'] = $this->error['code'];
        } else {
            $data['error_code'] = '';
        }

        // Making of Breadcrumbs to be displayed on site
        $data['breadcrumbs']   = array();
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => false
        );
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_module'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => ' :: '
        );
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('module/mysite', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => ' :: '
        );

        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('module/mysite', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');

        $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');

        // This block parses the status (enabled / disabled)
        if (isset($this->request->post['mysite_status'])) {
            $data['mysite_status'] = $this->request->post['mysite_status'];
        } else {
            $data['mysite_status'] = $this->config->get('mysite_status');
        }

        $data['header']      = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer']      = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('module/mysite.tpl', $data));

    }

    protected function validate()
    {
        // Block to check the user permission to manipulate the module
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'module/mysite')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
        }

        // Block returns true if no error is found, else false if any error detected
        if (!$this->error) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /* Event Handlers */

    public function on_order_history_add($order_id)
    {
        // Load order data
        $this->load->model('checkout/order');
        $orderData = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($order_id);

        // Debug
        $this->logger->write(print_r($orderData, true));

        // TODO: call third-party api & create hosting package
        // TODO: send success/error email notification to customer
    }
}
```

**admin\language\english\module\mysite.php**

```
<?php

// Heading
$_['heading_title']       = 'My Site';

// Text
$_['text_module']         = 'Modules';
$_['text_edit']           = 'Edit My Site Module';
$_['text_success']        = 'Success: You have modified module My Site!';

// Entry
$_['entry_status']        = 'Status:';

// Error
$_['error_permission']    = 'Warning: You do not have permission to modify module My Site!';
$_['error_code']          = 'Code Required';
```

**admin\view\template\module\mysite.tpl**

```
<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?>

<div id="content">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" form="form-helloworld" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_save; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
        <a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_cancel; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a></div>
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <?php echo $error_warning; ?>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo $text_edit; ?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-helloworld" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-status"><?php echo $entry_status; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select name="mysite_status" id="input-status" class="form-control">
                <?php if ($mysite_status) { ?>
                <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                <option value="0"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <option value="1"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>          
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

When I install the module (I am developing in WAMP), I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in H:\wamp\www\mysite.local\system\engine\controller.php on line 10

Any ideas what this error is about? When I refresh the page, it does say the module is installed, when I try to uninstall it, I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original constructor was setting up the `$this->registry` object. You are overriding the constructor (`system/engine/controller.php:2`). So use

```
public function __construct($registry)
  {
     parent::__construct( $registry );
     $this->error  = array();
     $this->logger = new Log('MySite.log');
  }
```

Comment: Ah, silly me. I forgot to check the controller when I received the error. You are right, this fixed my error.